# не устанавливается пакеты в атом

Tags: atom

при вводе чего либо в поиск выдает ошибку 'certificate has expired' что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а каким образом заголовок вопроса связан с тем, что написано в теле вопроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже никак, проект закрыли и заархивировали. Можно считать, что теперь это просто пустышка. Можешь скачать VScode и если нравится тема Атома, установи расширение Atomize (Atom One Dark theme)